# While loop until a condition is met for every cell in a column

Tags: excel, vba

Problem: Add 'Periodicity' values (with a nested if statement) to the 'Draft date' until the date is greater than or equal to the 'Cut off date'. Repeat for all cells in a column.

Referring to the example image: In cell S28 (5/09/2019), it has applied the formula of 'P28+14' but the adjusted date (19/09/2019) is still less than the cut off date (of 25/11/2019). The macro should repeat this periodicity formula until the adjusted date reaches 28/11/2019 (5 additional iterations).

I have tried using a Do While loop where values in the 'Change baseline' loop while the value is still "Yes"... but I was not successful due to my lack of VBA experience.

Example Periodicity formula in cell S4:

```
=IF($G4="Weekly",P4+7,
   IF($G4="Fortnightly",P4+14,
     IF($G4="Monthly",EDATE(P4,1),
       IF($G4="2-Monthly",EDATE(P4,2),
        IF($G4="Quarterly",EDATE(P4,3),
          IF($G4="6-Monthly",EDATE(P4,6),"No"))))))
```

Example Periodicity formula in VBA:

```
"=IF(RC7=""Weekly"",RC[-3]+7,IF(RC7=""Fortnightly"",RC[-3]+14,IF(RC7=""Monthly"",EDATE(RC[-3],1),IF(RC7=""2-Monthly"",EDATE(RC[-3],2),IF(RC7=""Quarterly"",EDATE(RC[-3],3),IF(RC7=""6-Monthly"",EDATE(RC[-3],6),""No""))))))"
```

[image]

Comment: Where is your code? Can you edit your question and post what you have so far.

Comment: Hi there, I believe posting my code will not add any value as it is my first time writing VBA code, I appreciate the response!  :)

Comment: I believe that if you don't post your code you will not be helped. This site offers assistance to those that show they have attempted to resolve their issue themselves.. Without your code and where you are going wrong, how do you expect anyone to help? We aren't going to write the code for you...

Comment: Thank you for the comment, I have edited the question with my current (very broken) attempt!

Comment: you want the macro to make a formula for you or do you want the exact calculated date in column S?

Comment: The macro should ideally calculate the exact final date in column S

Comment: ... and you got an naswer 1 minute after posting your code. Does the answer below fix your problem?

Comment: Awesome, thank you all! I have edited and added the corrected VBA code into the question.

Comment: @JkJkJake I rolled back your post to the original question. If you found a solution please provide it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make a function which will give you the date more than the cutoff date, instead of using the formula, that way you can use this function in our formula or your subroutine.

```vb
Function getModifiedDate(date,cutoff,periodicity)
  while date<cutoff
    if periodicity="Monthly" then
        date=date+ 1 month 'your logic to make it add a month (+1 will add a day)
    'elseif periodicity='....
    '....
    'and so on...
    end if
  wend
  getModifiedDate=date
end Function
```

Now inside your subroutine, loop through the cells you want, and use the function defined earlier.

or directly use the formula in your S column
`=getModifiedDate(P5,P$1,Q5)` and you should get the modified date.